# What accent do trolls in Discworld have?

Tags: languages, discworld, language-explanation

> “Dis der Riot Act and you’ve all got to read it, right?
>
> “Boys, if dere was a PhD in bein’ fick, youse wouldn’t be able to find a pencil.”

These are a couple of quotes from Detritus, the Troll in the Watch.

Are the words “dis”, “der”, “dere”, and “fick” an attempt at transcribing a particular accent, e.g. cockney? What about “youse”, which sounds more Scots? Are these words trying to indicate a low level of education or intelligence?

Comment: At some point it is revealed that the crystalline troll brains do not work well at Ank Morpork temperature. When Detritus is trapped in a refrigerated warehouse his brain powers up to full capacity and (amongst other things) his enunciation improves markedly, so yes, this has something to do with intelligence.

Comment: In my head it always sounded like the sterotypical gangster/mob heavy. "Mr Crysoprase is very angry wit you...". I can't find a video showing what I mean now.

Comment: In the Nigel Planer audiobooks, the trolls have a pronounced Scottish accent

Comment: We don’t got no accents. Youse is der ones wiv der funny accents.

Comment: @Darren that was my first thought when I read the examples.  The stereotype is based on an Irish-derived New York city accent originally native to the Tenderloin, which fits fairly well with AaakahM's answer below.

Comment: The troll speak always puts me in mind of the Star Trek TOS episode 'A piece of the action', the gangsters all spoke like that, and of course our Jim with... "Scotty, dis is Koik"

Answer (score 11):

It's not cockney - it's just a common (as in low, not widespread) southern accent associated with uneducated thugs or gang heavies (even youse is used by this stereotype in some contexts, such as "any of youse know how much trouble you're in?")

For an example of how this sounds:

Compare this with the East London/Cockney accents of characters like Eddy, Turkish and Brick-Top in *Lock, Stock and Two Smoking Barrels* and *Snatch*.

Comment: This. I was going to paste [dis link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XnKWH2HfoMU) but yours - sorry, youse -  is better.

Answer (score 10):

The features suggested by these spellings are:

- [Th-fronting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th-fronting) ("This" -> "Dis", and "thick" -> "fick")

  > Th-fronting is a prominent feature of several dialects of English,
  >   notably Cockney, Essex dialect, Estuary English, some West Country and
  >   Yorkshire dialects, African American Vernacular English, and Liberian
  >   English, as well as in many non-native English speakers (e.g. Hong
  >   Kong English, though the details differ among those accents).
- [g-dropping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_English_consonant_clusters#G-dropping) ("being" -> "bein'")

  > Today, G-dropping is a feature of colloquial and non-standard speech
  >   of all regions, including stereotypically of Cockney, Southern
  >   American English and African American Vernacular English. Its use is
  >   highly correlated with the socioeconomic class of the speaker, with
  >   speakers of lower classes using /n/ with greater frequency. It has
  >   also been found to be more common among men than women, and less
  >   common in more formal styles of speech.
- [A particular informal plural form of you](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You#Informal_plural_forms) ("youse")

  > Ireland, Tyneside, Merseyside, Central Scotland, Australia, Falkland Islands, New Zealand, Philadelphia, Rural Canada

There doesn't seem to be one single accent that's mentioned in all three of those wikipedia pages. Were it not for that 'youse' I'd say that surely Cockney was intended, but I can't square that with 'youse' at all.

Comment: Being American, I more equated the Troll accents with that of areas in New York City.  Also, as there are many troll gangsters, I hear them in the style of characters from Damon Runyon stories like Guys and Dolls and Little Miss Marker.

Comment: @VBartilucci I hear you, but do those accents have 'fick' for 'thick'?